# What exactly does getchar() do in this code.. [C]

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what getchar() does in this code, can anybody help explain it?

```
int main(void)
{
  int i, n;

  printf("This program prints a table of squares.\n");
  printf("Enter number of entries in table: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  getchar();


  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printf("%10d%10d\n", i, i * i);
    if (i % 24 == 0) {
      printf("Press Enter to continue...");
      getchar();   
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=getchar+in+c) returned a lot of results, one of which is [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It blocks the program until the user presses enter.  The character the user typed is just thrown away since the return value isn't passed to a local variable.

I looks like the intent is to add simple pagination functionality since it does this after every 24 lines.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` returns the next character from the standard input (stdin).
In your program second getchar() occurence should be checked if the entered key is "**Enter**".Asci value of Enter key is 13.

Answer (score 0):

getchar() returns a character from stdin.

Here each getchar(); waits for user to press a key so it can return a single character. It's here in code to wait for user interaction.

But the shell terminal do not pass the charater as soon as you press keyboard. It passes it to stdin stream only after you press enter/New line, which is also a character.

So, when you only press Enter/NL key, getchar() will receive 0xA.

But if you press some other character and then Enter/NL, the first getchar() will get that other character and subsequent getchar() will get 0xA. This is like a simple pipe mechanism.